# How can I send 2 orders using nRF24L01

Tags: nrf24l01+

My project is to control a servo with a joystick using nRF24L01. I have this code working well, but the problem is that I want to add a lamp in the receiver side, and a switch in the transmitter side. I had tried so many codes from the internet, but nothing works. When I implement the code for the led, the servo and the joystick will stop working unfortunately.
Maybe the problem could be solved by transmitting on 2 channels each channel has a command.  But, the question is how this is the transmitter code that is working normally :

Transmitter Code

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>


RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";


void setup() {

  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address); // 00002
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}

void loop() {
delay(5);






 radio.stopListening();
  int potValue = analogRead(A0);
  int angleValue = map(potValue, 0, 1024, 0, 23.5);
 radio.write(&angleValue, sizeof(angleValue));

  delay(5);
  radio.startListening();
  
  
}
```

and this is the receiver code:

Receiver Code

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <Servo.h>



RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";
boolean button_state = 0;

Servo myServo;




void setup() {
 
    Serial.begin(9600);
  myServo.attach(5);

  
  radio.begin();
  
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address); // 00002
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  
}

void loop() {

  delay(5);
  radio.startListening();
 
  if ( radio.available()) {
while (radio.available()) {
  
      int angleV = 0;
      radio.read(&angleV, sizeof(angleV));
     myServo.write(angleV);
      }
    

   
    
    delay(5);
    radio.stopListening();
    
  }}
```

Comment: `i had tried soo many codes from the internet` ... that is your problem ... copy & paste programming ... please do yourself a favor and learn what your existing program is actually doing ... you may find that it is actually easy to add another piece of data to the transmission